# Facebook SSO Showing Wrong Language

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharekit

I implemented ShareKit 2.0 fork for Video Sharing https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/212

When the user first logs in to facebook, it switches to Facebook, pulls the correct app info, and is all in English, but at the top right corner, instead of the button reading Login, it says Ingia.  Any ideas if this is a Facebook problem or something weird in the iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Facebook issue:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383